# Unable to get sub element using PHP dom parser

Tags: php, dom

**Below is my Html**

```
<div class="product4Col">
   <div class="fluidprodCol">
      <div class="fluid">
         <a href="url1">Title 1</a>  
      </div>
      <div class="fluid">
         <div>
            <a id="">Add To Bag</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName title">
         <a href="url2">Subtitle 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName price"><label>₹</label>2,999 
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName">
         <div class="colorSwatch" ></div>
         <div class="colorSwatch" ></div>
         <div class="colorSwatch" ></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product4Col">
   <div class="fluidprodCol">
      <div class="fluid">
         <a href="url11">Title 2</a>     
      </div>
      <div class="fluid">
         <div>
            <a id="">Add To Bag</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName title">
         <a href="url22">Subtitle 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName price"><label>₹</label>2,999 
      </div>
      <div class="fluid productName">
         <div class="colorSwatch" ></div>
         <div class="colorSwatch" ></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**i want to get output like below**

1: url1 , Title 1 , url2 , Subtitle 1, 3 colorSwatch

2: url11 ,Title 2 , url22 , Subtitle 2, 2 colorSwatch

I tried the below code but it seems not working as expected, I am unable to level 2 data, i want to get url, title and swatches count.
Need help to fix the issue

```
$dataop = file_get_contents('http://localhost/dataimport.html');


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($dataop);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='product4Col']");
foreach($nodeList as $prg){
    echo "<br>------------------<br>";
    $nodeListnx = $prg->query("//div[@class='fluidprodCol']");
    foreach($nodeListnx as $prgnx){
        echo "<p>new</p>";
    }
    echo "<br>------------------<br>";
}
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting - there is no `query` method on DomElement objects. You need to use the `$xpath->query()` again, but provide the `$prg` variable as the second argument for context.

Answer (score 0):

This code corrects the problem pointed out with the second use of `query()` and uses the `$prg` as the context for the next search.  But I've also added the `.` to the start of the query to ensure it reads only the contents of this node.

As this extracts the `<a>` tags inside this element, it picks out only the data from the 1st and 3rd links.  It then looks as the `colorSwatch` classed elements, not sure what you wanted to do with them, so it just outputs the content...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($dataop);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='product4Col']");
foreach($nodeList as $prg){
    echo "<br>------------------<br>";
    $nodeListnx = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='fluidprodCol']//a", $prg);
    echo $nodeListnx[0]->attributes['href']->textContent . " " . $nodeListnx[0]->textContent . "<br /";
    echo $nodeListnx[2]->attributes['href']->textContent . " " . $nodeListnx[2]->textContent. "<br /";
    
    $colorSwatchs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='colorSwatch']", $prg);
    foreach ( $colorSwatchs as $colorSwatch )   {
        echo $colorSwatch->textContent . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<br>------------------<br>";
}
```